# :nth-child(2) and :nth-of-type(2) not selecting

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML, and I want to select the second child `div`:

```
<div class="header content">
    <div class="widget block block-static-block"></div>
    <div class="widget block block-static-block"></div> <!-- this is the one I want to select -->
</div>
```

Ive tried the following CSS:

```
.header.content .widget.block-static-block:nth-of-type(2) {}
.header.content .widget.block-static-block:nth-child(2) {}
```

And neither of them work in selecting this `div`.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This should work, it works in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c490kooj/#&togetherjs=sBozQgKB2L   My guess is you style sheet is not referenced properly.

Comment: `:nth-child` or `:nth-of-type` has nothing to do with classes, all you need here is `.header div:nth-child(2)` or if you have other elements between `div` tags than use `:nth-of-type`

Comment: Both work fine, but note that pseudo classes operate on elements, not classes of elements.

Comment: I think in the actual code there is some other `div` element in between those two. That's the only case where these selectors will not work.

Comment: It is conceivable that a more specific rule is overriding the one you give.

Comment: the stylesheet is loaded fine. when i inspect the second `div` in firefox the `:nth-child(2)` rules doesnt even appear, so its not being over written. funnily enough `:last-child` does work, but `:nth-child` does not, i tested `:nth-child(1)` and `(3)` and neither of them worked, not even `first-child` worked - and although `.header.content` contains other `divs` it does not contain any others with that specific class `.widget.block.block-static-block`

Comment: @Jimmery: The other `divs` - are they in between these two? If yes, they are the reason. `nth-*` selectors work on the elements and any classes that are added are only extra conditions and not main conditions. That is, the first child is always the first child irrespective of whether it has the class or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have only two, you can select it with

```
.widget.block.block-static-block:last-child{
//your code
}
```

Comment: If `nth-child` doesn't work, then why would this work?

Comment: I tested it on a HTML file. I inserted a text on both divs and changed the color, only at the last one using last-child only. It worked fine

Comment: Read my comment again. I'm not saying `last-child` will not work--of course it will. I'm asking why you think `nth-child` or `nth-of-type` did not work, because if you don't have a theory about that, there is no guarantee that your alternative solution will work either.

Comment: this worked for me when `:nth-child` did not... go figure?

Comment: It's a fact that I can't explain it either. I have encountered the same problem myself many times, and I always try other solutions, like last or adding a class or something else. But I can't answer the reason why this doesn't work, although it should.